# Specifying the return type of SQL case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following SQL case statement.

```
select tracking_num,
case
    when source_one is not null then source_one
    else source_two
end source_value
from ...
```

source_one and source_two are double precision. If I execute the above SQL I the source_value column returned is of int precision.

A coworker suggested adding ohd_ to the beginning of the column name.

```
select tracking_num,
case
    when source_one is not null then source_one
    else source_two
end ohd_source_value
from ...
```

This returns the correct value (The returned column is named 'source_value').

Is the ohd_ prefix a oracle standard? I cannot find documentation anywhere. Also, is there a better way to perform this conversion? Perhaps by using the CAST keyword?

Thank you in advanced for your response.

*DB Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit*

Edit: As a followup to the ohd_ prefix that I mentioned. It turns out that this is baked into our client as a work around to oracle bug #1312311. OHD stands for "Oracle Hack Double" apparently.

Comment: Why don't you just use `COALESCE(source_one,source_two)`? I'd be amazed if Oracle changes its behaviour due to your choice of column prefix BTW!

Comment: +1 to Tony; wish it were an answer. Never heard of an "ohd" prefix either, but it might be related to whatever client is receiving the rows.  Note that if you are just running a "select", the columns don't really have a "type".

Comment: i don't think it's possible to mix two column types in a case statement. oracle will implicitly convert to varchar2.

Comment: You haven't said where you're calling this from, possibly your client is doing something odd, but just out of interest does your table also have a column called `source_value` that might be confusing the client as well? It wouldn't confuse the query itself, but maybe you have a layer that's inferring the type from the table definition. Seems kinda unlikely...

Comment: Thanks Tony, I forgot about COALESCE. Unfortunately I still have the same problem with data "types". I agree with Bob. I believe this might be specific to the client that is receiving the rows. That wouldn't be the first undocumented "feature" I have encountered. I will find someone with privileges to run the SQL directly and try it out.

Comment: @Alex, the column is actually named percent_split, I just renamed it for this example.

Comment: I just had an administrator run the code outside of our client. The data type thing is baked into the client. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circumstance doesn't seem right.

Oracle is not, by itself without some coded intervention, converting types based solely on the column alias.

However, to be completely certain of your returned type you can [CAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm) the selected value in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: The ohd_ prefix is baked into our client. The code was performing the conversion. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please post a simple example showing what you say is going on.  Unless I misunderstand your situation, I don't see any conversion happening.

```
SQL> drop table testx
Table dropped.
SQL> create table testx
(
 pk number,
 d1 BINARY_DOUBLE
)
Table created.
SQL> drop table testy
Table dropped.
SQL> create table testy
(
  pk number,
  d1 BINARY_DOUBLE
)
Table created.
SQL> insert into testx values (1, 100)
1 row created.
SQL> insert into testx values (2, null)
1 row created.
SQL> insert into testy values (1, 200)
1 row created.
SQL> insert into testy values (2, 201)
1 row created.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> drop table testz
Table dropped.
SQL> create table testz as
select x.pk,
case when (x.d1 is not null) then x.d1
else y.d1
end new_d1
from testx x, testy y
where x.pk = y.pk
Table created.
SQL> select column_name || ' => ' ||  data_type
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'TESTZ'

COLUMN_NAME||'=>'||DATA_TYPE                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PK => NUMBER                                                                    
NEW_D1 => BINARY_DOUBLE                                                         

2 rows selected.
```

Also note that I typically don't use BINARY_DOUBLE (I just use NUMBER type), but you specifically stated "source_one and source_two are double precision" so I inferred this.